# Linux install on Kangaroo Plus

Tags: boot, usb-creator

I am trying to use my Mac to write a boot disk for a recently purchased Kangaroo Plus computer that has no OS on it. I first used unetbootin to create a usb boot disk with ubuntu-15.04-desktop-iso and then when I start the kangaroo plus it gives me the option to install Ubuntu but after I hit enter the screen went black for at least 2 hours and nothing happened. I powered off and restarted and tried the OEM install and same thing. Any suggestions on how to get Ubuntu (any version) on this portable computer? Thanks in advance for any help I appreciate it!

Comment: Question - In BIOS (hit F2 at power on), navigate to the Configuration tab. Do you see an option at the bottom of that page to reorder boot devices?

Comment: On the configuration screen I can see a EFI boot order line

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I have not fully solved it, but got further.
I was trying to install Ubuntu 14.10.

Here is a partial solution:

- Use F2 at boot time.
- Disable Secure Boot mode (I don't have the machine with me, so I can't offer exact navigation right now).
- Save the settings
- Reboot.
- Then both the live Ubuntu mode and install will run.

BUT - after install, it crashed on the first boot (lots of "got data interrupt even though no data operation was in progress"), and then get hung on the purple screen the next time(s) I booted.

On my own, I'm planning to boot Ubuntu while showing boot messages, and/or installing more recent Ubuntu (15) - just to see what works.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for you tip. Once I disabled secure boot, the installer ran. It got almost all the way through but gave the grub-eft-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay sorry previous comment was for Ubuntu 14.04-3. When I followed suggestion(disabled secure boot) for 15.10-amd-desktop it installed and is running. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You may want to edit the kernelparamer from splash to noplymouth and remove quiet.

This will tell you more about want is goning on and reveal a important errror message.

Comment: So I am using GNU grub version 2.02~beta-Suubuntu.3

Comment: Programs Install Ubuntu

Comment: Programs Install Ubuntu. Fist line says set gfxpayload=keep.  Second line says linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=cdrom/pressed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only ubiquity quiet splash. Third line says initrd /casper/initrd.lz.  Processor is 1.44 GHz Intel Atom x5-Z8500. Graphics are Integrated Intel HD graphics. Any help greatly appreciated